# How to find replacement lockout cartridge for Marzocchi MZ Race 2006 fork?

Tags: fork, compatibility, lockout

I want to replace broken Suntour cartidge for my Marzocchi MZ Race 100mm 2006 fork.
It became very soft and lockout doesn't work. But there is no model or serial number marking on the cartridge itself. Official fork manual says nothing about this cartridge. Also I can't find exact replacement at any online parts suppliers. What are my options? Is it possible to fit some other Suntour cartridge with similar measurements?

Fork serial is:
3116B0113
T06D1223
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]